# Gson serialize issue with backslashes java

Tags: java, json, gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String path = "/folder1/folder2".replaceAll("/","\\\\/");//for get \/folder1\/folder2
String result = gson.toJson(path);
```

and the result is \\/folder1\\/folder2

Comment: the result is with 2 backslashes \\/folder1\\/folder2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path contains backslashes, and those are being escaped by `toJson()`. When you deserialize at the other end, you'll end up with a string of `\/folder1\/folder2` via normal JSON unescaping. I don't see this as an issue: the aim of serialization is that you get the same data out at the far end as you put in this end. Your input is `\/folder1\/folder2`, and so is your output - the fact that that requires escaping along the way is irrelevant.

It does raise the question as to why you want `\/` in the string at all though. Are you trying to escape the forward slashes manually? You don't need to do that. I strongly suspect you should just have `/folder1/folder2` without any replacement.

EDIT: From the comments, it looks like you have a requirement *you don't even understand* to escape `/`. While it turns out that that it's valid to escape any character in JSON, the requirement of escaping `/` is distinctly non-standard, and I suspect you'll have a hard time finding a JSON library which allows you to say that you need it to be escaped.

I suggest you revisit whatever is imposing this requirement on you, and try to fix it so that it accepts standard JSON without escaping the `/`. Trying to add the extra level of escaping manually will *not* work.

Comment: I want \/folder1\/folder2 but I got \\/folder1\\/folder2 problem with double backslashes

Comment: @Lyudvig: You'll get `\\/folder1\\/folder2` *as the JSON*, but then it will be deserialized to the same string as your input. If you want `\/folder1\/folder2` as the JSON, I think you'll have a hard time achieving that - and you shouldn't *want* to achieve it, as `/` doesn't need to be escaped in JSON. It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do or why.

Comment: {ifs:[{text:"sample1a",id:"\/sequel\/repository\/sample1\/sample1a",cls:"folder"}, {text:"sample1b",id:"\/sequel\/repository\/sample1\/sample1b",cls:"folder"}, {text:"custlist.vpt",id:"\/sequel\/repository\/sample1\/custlist.vpt",cls:"file", leaf:true}]}

Comment: I want output like this but can't get single backslashes

Comment: and I get \\/folder1\\/folder2 as String not as Json

Comment: @Lyudvig: I think you're confused - that *is* the JSON (as a string). Once you deserialize, you'll get a value of `id` with `\/` in. But you *shouldn't* want `\/` in the JSON - there's just no need for it. Why do you *want* the backslashes? Backslashes are normally used in JSON to escape characters such as `"`, but you just don't need to escape `/`.

Comment: @Lyudvig: Yes, I know what your code will do: it will give the *correctly JSON-escaped* value for `\/folder1\/folder2`, because that's what you asked it to do...

Comment: actually I don't get it. Can you receive \/folder1\/folder2 from json ?

Comment: @Lyudvig: Yes, when you parse the JSON again, that's the value you'll get back, because it will unescape the double backslash to a single backslash.

Comment: actually  here's what I have I have a class calls IntegrationFileObject which have a field called id ( path of file) and I need to parse it to Json(as String) and put it in request. request would be like this {ifs:[{text:"sample1a",id:"\/sequel\/repository\/sample1\/sample1a",cls:"folder"‌​}, {text:"sample1b",id:"\/sequel\/repository\/sample1\/sample1b",cls:"folder"}, {text:"custlist.vpt",id:"\/sequel\/repository\/sample1\/custlist.vpt",cls:"file"‌​, leaf:true}]}

Comment: why request like that I don't know it's just a need

Comment: so I can't get that single slashes

Comment: @Lyudvig: "it's just a need" is never enough information. Basically you're asking for something which isn't required by normal JSON, and I suspect you won't find it supported by normal JSON libraries. `/` doesn't need escaping, and "manually" escaping it yourself will indeed lead to the double-escaping you're seeing. I suggest you find out what is imposing this odd requirement.

Comment: and I need Json as String for request